# jQuery does not capture certain combination of keypresses (for example, ZXW)

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you press simultaneusely Z X and W, third keypress would not be captured.
You'll hear some beep sound. 
This happens on Windows machine, in Chrome browser.

What this could be? Some reserved combination?

Comment: Here's a link to JSFiddle, with working demonstration - https://jsfiddle.net/wnhxLxnj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another keyboard. In order to save money, keyboard manufacturers often put many keys on the same "circuit" of sorts within the wiring of the keyboard. This prevents multiple keys in the same region of the keyboard from being pressed simultaneously. Sometimes it even prevents more than 2 keys at all from across the whole keyboard being pressed at once.